# Storing site data in columns or rows

Tags: mysql, storing-data

This is a question of how to perform the best practice of storing data from a webpage. Like texts/image-urls/links etc.

I have an CMS were you can create web pages. Here you can edit texts/upload images. In the future it would also be nice to "add new elements", add links to a-tags etc.

I need to have a robust and flexible solution that also have good performance. In both getting/recieving this data.

Lets consider I have 1000 pages with each around 25 elements on each page that can be updated and stored in the database.

Alternative 1)

Create a table and 1 column for each element on these pages for example columns like:
title_1, title_2,image_1,image_2.

Here we have a set of columns that we can update, these we can use on the web page.

Alternative 2)

Create 1 table with the columns (id, namespace, page_id, data)

And for each element on the page I add the namespace in association with the page_id to make the data output unique. In the data I can add any kind of information; text, links etc.

What do you suggest as a good solution for this issue? I'm ofcourse also open for other alternatives.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend option two, with the addition of a column identifying the element id/or type, if indeed the element id is somehow comparable. That is to say, if anchor text (say) is always stored as element id = 4, then you might want an element id = 4 so that you could compare anchor texts across multiple documents.

If, on the other hand (and this is the scenario I imagine is more likely), you may have 1-25 elements on a page and each of them could be different (eg document one has three anchor texts and four images, document two has one anchor text and no images, etc) it would make sense to add an element_type_id table that stores a bit of information about the element types. This is assuming that you ever have any interest in comparing (say) images across multiple documents, or anchor texts across multiple documents, etc.

Another thing to consider: if you are likely to see the same element over and over again, it actually makes more sense to effectively parameterize those elements by way of a lookup table. So basically store each (say) unique anchor text in one table and reference its id in your actual data table.

If I may add one additional thing: SO may not be the best place for the particular question you are asking. I'm not totally sure of that and maybe I'm wrong... but I would poke around the Stack Exchange network and see if other forums more closely deal with the type of question you asking. In the very least, I'd observe that your question is fairly vague and the goal of achieving a "robust and flexible solution that also {has} good performance. In both getting/recieving this data." is not likely to be accomplished simply by asking for advice on SO. There is a *LOT* that goes into data architecture, and certainly many of the details I would consider important in designing this myself are not present in your questions. And if you're not sure what those details are, I am not sure if SO is really the best place to set about learning them. I think https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ may be a better fit for this question.

Just my opinion, and I could be wrong. Either way, I would consider learning a bit about database normal forms (http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm or Google it) as well as do a little research on the types of design considerations that go into building a database (an old but still good SO article on that is here: [What are the most important considerations when designing a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580233/what-are-the-most-important-considerations-when-designing-a-database))